# JSF lifecycle with example

Tags: jsf

JSF lifecycle with real example.

JSF have request,processvalidation,render respose,invoke application,update model values.These event when should occuring in the real application ?

For example:

Login application.

username,password:checking in the database.so Could please give me the how the lifecycle occuring in this application.

Please help me.

Answer (score 12):

There is an excellent tutorial by BalusC here:
[Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html).

If you take the time to read it and put it into practice you'll acquire a pretty nice understanding of the JSF lifecycle.