# Jsf Template Showing Incorrect Url

Tags: jsf, servlets, jsf-2, richfaces, servlet-filters

I am using jsf2 and RichFaces. I want to track each page being browsed by the user.

For that I have created Servelet Filter  which  Intercepts the page being requested. In my project, I am using jsf template features  where header and Footer are fixed. In the body part, I have defined menu.xhtml   and an iframe  tag. Response is targeted on to iframe whenever user clicks on any link on the menu.

My Problem is that, I am not getting the correct url of the page requested  in the filter.

**My Filter Snap**

Below Shown is the Filter,looking For xhtml Page.

```
chain.doFilter(request, response);

HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
if( null != session && (uri.contains(".xhtml") || null != session.getAttribute("userid"))){
    if(null != session.getAttribute("userid")){
        String userid = session.getAttribute("userid").toString();
        //for saving usage details 
        if(uri.contains(".xhtml")){                           
            System.out.println(".......Requeted Page.........."+req.getRequestURL().toString());
        saveUserUsage(req);
        }
    }
}
```

url getting in the filter is userdeskop.xhtml even though different links in the menu are selected.

Comment: Have you checked i.e. via Firebug, if after clicking the Links in your browser the expected .xhtml/.jsf pages is requested/retrieved? I would guess, independent from what you click, the page requested by your browser is always the same.

Comment: i have used iframe in my tempalte.

Comment: Well, the iFrame-Request should still be shown by FireBug after you request it/click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for the same url independent from the clicked menu might be the [JSF Lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770543/):

- it decides on server side on which page to deliver.

From that side, independent from what you click on e.g. a JSF Mojarra Implementation, the requested page might always be the same - just the parameters differ ... and the server does a redirect to the desired page (which is just too late for your filter to be recognized ;-) ).

**Update**: I would try to get a phase listener being executed before or after *RENDER RESPONSE* phase, because there the navigation goal should be resolved. Within the listener something like (untested example code)

```
public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event)
{
  FacesContext context = event.getFacesContext();
  String viewId = context.getViewRoot().getViewId();
  ....
 }
```

might help you resolve the final url.

If you *only* want to resolve the urls for the main menu (I guess, that links are static and no managed bean method needs to be invoked), you can alternatively use `h:outputLink`, which resolves to fixed urls ( see [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4317723/1269441) for details) - this will work with your already existing listener.

Hope it helps...

Comment: any solution to get the url back in filter?
@L-Ray

Comment: See the update. Give feedback if it works... and yes, upvotes appreciated.

Comment: view id  is not showing full url.if the url  to be shown  would be http://localhost:8080/authenticationmodule/faces/xhtml/authentication/userUsageDetails.xhtml, getting only  xhtml/authentication/userUsageDetails.xhtml  any solution @L-Ray