# Jsf El Expression getter and setter ArrayList

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, arraylist

i m using inside the backing bean an

```
private ArrayList<String> myList;


init(){
  myList = new ArrayList<String>();
  myList.add("XYZ");
}

public ArrayList<String> getMyList(){
    return myList;
}

public setMyList(ArrayList<String> l){
    myList = l;

}
```

insde the xhtml

i show the elements by doing:

```
   <h:outputText value="Item: " />  
                <p:inputText required="true" label="Item"  
                        value="#{mybean.myList[0]}" />
```

when i show the page i see the value:

```
 XYZ
```

in the page.

So my question is:

If I do NOT set "XYZ" inside the ArrayList and the user writes inside `p:inputText` the value "HKJ", will I find on server-side inside `myList` at position 0 the expected "HKJ"?
Can I use `ArrayList` for display and set values or do i have to use `String[]` ?

you can find here similar question:

```
  http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t303520-jsf-using-arrays-arraylist-in-the-backing-bean.html
```

Comment: Isn't that expected behaviour of the JSF Lifecycle? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770543

Comment: i m only asking if it is the same for arrays.

Comment: You can use either ArrayList or String[]. Both way it will work with the same syntax that you have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF is working in a Lifecycle (see [JSF lifecycle with example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770543)). One of the first parts of this lifecycle is to take user-sent input, validate it and push it into the JSF object tree.

So, when you connect a `h:inputText`s value with a managed beans property - this field will be updated with the input a user did on the frontend (when it passes the validation, and the input field is inside a `h:form`).

The collection access operator (`[]` operator) works in the case you describe the same for Arrays and Collections (`ArrayList` implements Collections).

Comment: the question is not about lifecycle in general but specific to the EL expression for arrays. My question is i can use Arraylist for display and set values or i must use String[]  ?

Comment: you can see this here also: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t303520-jsf-using-arrays-arraylist-in-the-backing-bean.html

Comment: Hi @frank, your questions was not clearly asked. This makes answering and actively helping you achieving your goals a bit difficult. Check out the edited answer above and good luck with your project. Upvote/Accepting appreciated.

Comment: i can't upvote o accept an answer that do not answer to my question

Comment: Question: Can I use ArrayList for display and set values or do i have to use String[] ? Answer:The collection access operator ([] operator) works in the case you describe the same for Arrays and Collections (ArrayList implements Collections).

Comment: this is the an answer. thanks. i will check this. i m still not on the point in the project that i can check this.

Comment: That was the updated Part - Sorry, next Time I'll mark it to be better readable. So, if this answer is useful for you, mark it as being so :-) Good luck and have fun ... :-)

Comment: do not worry i will accept soon ;) thx for your say your opinion.